# CSS fallback for Twitter Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this sounds silly, but does anyone know how to implement CSS fallback for [Twitter Bootstrap Carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) for JavaScript disabled browsers (or in case, the necessary JavaScript files don't load properly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this page that at least does have an [automatically rotating CSS carousel](http://csswizardry.com/2011/10/fully-fluid-responsive-css-carousel/). However, considering that even this requires CSS3 I just assume the case would be quite limited...

Comment: Please also consider non-CSS3/non-JS users, e.g. making the carousel items position:relative if JS is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check [GitHubGist - barryvdh / carousel.js](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151)

> Bootstrap Carousel, with jQuery fallback for Internet Explorer (To
>   have sliding images)